# How can a service principal login to my Azure app-service?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have enabled authentication in my app service by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad Now whenever I access my web site endpoint, I get redirected to Azure AD login page and am able to proceed when I enter my credentials. How can I login using a service principal credentials? The login page obviously does not accept a client id. Is there some header I should populate to make a successful request using service principal credentials?

An insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, interactive authentication flows (like login page) do not apply for applications and service principals, they are meant only for end users.

A few important points on how to proceed further:

1. Make use of a non-interactive authentication flow, like [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to acquire token.

   You can make use of the relevant ADAL Libraries depending on your platform, or hit Azure AD endpoint directly.

   Here is a sample that hits Azure AD endpoint directly. This sample makes use of client secret, it's also possible to use certificate instead of secret, in case that's relevant for your case. A sample in the link for client credentials grant that I shared above does show that.

   ```
   POST /contoso.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: login.microsoftonline.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=625bc9f6-3bf6-4b6d-94ba-e97cf07a22de&client_secret=qkDwDJlDfig2IpeuUZYKH1Wb8q1V0ju6sILxQQqhJ+s=&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
   ```

   Here is another sample that makes use of ADAL for .NET - [Calling a Web API in a daemon app or long-running process](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)

   One important part of code for you to notice is in [Program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/blob/master/TodoListDaemon/Program.cs)

   ```
   authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
   clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
   AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
   ```

   You haven't mentioned which platform you're using explicitly, so I have shared .NET sample as that's the one I'm most familiar with. In case you need a different one, refer to this guidance on Microsoft Docs - [Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries), it links to all the different supported Microsoft Libraries and each has a few relevant samples.
2. From a permissions standpoint, your service principal will need to be assigned `Application Permissions` for the relevant web application. Another type of permissions are `Delegated Permissions` but they are only applicable for users.
3. As you ask about what header to populate, it will be the standard `Authorization` header. Format of the value is `Bearer <access token>`. In case you make use of Authentication libraries like ADAL, then library would take care of this part, but if you're doing hitting the REST endpoints directly, then you need to populate the header.

Comment: Could you point me to some smple ADAL  code that acquires token from Azure Active directory using service principal credentials?

Comment: @user3740951 sure.. I have edited my answer (point 1) to include a code sample that shows how to acquire token.

Comment: @user3740951 one more quick point.. do notice that I have shared all information related to Azure AD v1.0 endpoint and ADAL libraries.. since the documentation you're following clearly mentions that Azure AD v2.0 (including MSAL) is not supported for Azure App Services yet.. but in future whenever that support comes, you should consider using V2 and MSAL instead.